# what we can do with 'else if 'that we cant do with 'else' in c language

Tags: c, if-statement

what we can do with 'else if 'that we cant do with 'else' in c language
    if(----){

```
printf("--");

}else{

}
```

and

```
if(----){

printf("--");

}else if("---"){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is Simple..

If and else are used, When you make a true or false statements.

**Example:**

```
If ( 3>2) 
{ printf ("3");}
else { printf ( "2");}
```

But in case of `if and else if`

**Example:**

```
if(3>2) {printf ("3");}
else if (2>3) {printf ("false");}
```

IN THIS WAY .. In  else if.  you should have a condition and it executes only when it is true.. but in case  of else ..it is executed when if condition is false  ..